# how to sort two dimensional array by one column in Java

Tags: java, sorting

So what I want is this

int[][] arr=new int[2][8];

input:

1 1 3 1 5 3 7 1

5 2 4 8 3 7 5 2

output:

1 1 5 3 1 7 3 1

2 2 3 4 5 5 7 8

you can see that it is sorted by the second row in ascending order and the first row just follows,
how can I do this? help, please.

I tried doing below

Arrays.sort(arr[1]);

but I don't think it is working. It does sort the second row in ascending order but the first row is not matching the initial pair with the second row

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {
        {1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1},
        {5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 5, 2}
    };

    List<int[]> list = new AbstractList<int[]>() {

        @Override
        public int[] get(int index) {
            return new int[] {array[1][index], array[0][index]};
        }

        @Override
        public int[] set(int index, int[] value) {
            int[] old = get(index);
            array[1][index] = value[0];
            array[0][index] = value[1];
            return old;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return array[0].length;
        }
    };

    Collections.sort(list, Arrays::compare);

    for (int[] row : array)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 7, 3, 1]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8]
```

Or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = {
        {1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1},
        {5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 5, 2}
    };

    int[] sortedIndexes = IntStream.range(0, array[0].length)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Integer i) -> array[1][i])
            .thenComparing(i -> array[0][i]))
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();

    int[][] output = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
        .mapToObj(r -> IntStream.range(0, array[r].length)
            .map(i -> array[r][sortedIndexes[i]])
            .toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

    for (int[] r : output)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

Comment: I was expecting using Arrays.sort() but I guess it is impossible.. I know I can solve this by making inner class that has two member variables and using Collections.sort(). So there isn't any way to solve this in a simple way isn't?

Comment: The inner class with the two member variables _is_ the simple solution in my opinion. If the two arrays contain values that are linked to each other, it's simpler to create one array with composite items.

Answer (score 0):

It may be implemented using helper method(s) to transpose the input array, then transposed array may be sorted by column, and transposed again to restore the original rows/cols:

```java
// create new array to store transposed
public static int[][] transpose(int[][] src) {
    return transpose(src, new int[src[0].length][src.length]);
}    

// use existing array to store the transposed
public static int[][] transpose(int[][] src, int[][] dst) {
    for (int i = 0, n = src.length; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, m = src[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            dst[j][i] = src[i][j];
        }
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Method `sortByColumn` (reusing the input array):

```java
public static void sortByColumn(int[][] arr, Comparator<int[]> comparator) {
    int[][] toSort = transpose(arr);
    Arrays.sort(toSort, comparator);
    transpose(toSort, arr);
}
```

Test:

```
int[][] arr = {
    {7, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4},
    {5, 2, 4, 8, 3, 7, 5, 2, 5}
};

sortByColumn(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(col -> col[1]));

for (int[] row : arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

Output:
in the first row values appear in the insertion order after sorting by the second element in each column.

```
[1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 4, 3, 1]
[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8]
```

---

Square arrays (width == height) may be transposed more efficiently without creating additional array:

```java
public static int[][] transposeSquare(int[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arr.length; i < n; i++) {
        // select the elements only above the main diagonal
        for (int j = i + 1, m = arr[i].length; j < m; j++) {
            int tmp = arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] = arr[j][i];
            arr[j][i] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: OP says "sorted by the second row in ascending order and the first row just follows". But Your solution seems to focus only on the second line.

Comment: Yes, _the first row just follows_ means the elements in the first row are taken from the corresponding column, their order is not affected.   If needed, the first row may be sorted too: `sortByColumn(arr, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(col -> col[1]).thenComparingInt(col -> col[0]));`